# Load more libraries when the map is already loaded

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The question seems obvious, but I cannot find an answer..

I have a web page, with a Google Maps loaded and shown.
Now I want to append a library (places, for example).

I don't want to modify the "main" script, since it is common for all the site, and the lib is needed on a few pages only.
Till now, appending a new script (sensor=false&libraries=places) worked fine, but it seems not  to work anymore.
Googe.load does not exist.

Is there any way to append a library instead of loading the whole script altogether?

I found this: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3664
but it's rather old - could be someone did find a way/workaround for the issue?

Comment: Are you sure you need to load the other libraries *after* Google Maps is loaded? Why not at the same time?

Comment: Yeah. `libraries=geometry,places`.

Comment: The site has map almost on any page, so the "main" maps API is loaded in the head. Unlike it, places is needed seldom, here and there, so it looks to me more correct to load it on demand and not always. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Andy I don't think that's what he asked for. But I don't have a solution for this. Google doesn't seem to have any documentation about loading a library apart from the main API.

Comment: I don't think there's any difference in code length between `libraries=geometry,places` and `libraries=geometry`. The OP is better off just changing the main script IMO.

Comment: The point here is that if you can't (or don't want to) change the HTML and that you already have the main API loaded: is there a way to just "append" the places or any other library independently?

Comment: @MrUpsidown , thanks, you got my point exactly.

Comment: I got your point but I am unable to get you an answer...